# Many to Many Spring Boot JPA not filling the ManyToMany Table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, orm

Hello guys I do have a following code:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Doctor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "doctor_patient",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="doctor_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns ={@JoinColumn(name="patient_id")})
    private Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<>();


    //getters and setters
}
```

and this entity also:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            },
    mappedBy = "patients")
    private Set<Doctor> doctorList = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and setters

}
```

This is the test I'm doing to use the snippets:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testSaveDoctor(){

    Doctor firstDoctor = new Doctor();
    firstDoctor.setFirstName("test doc");
    firstDoctor.setLastName("lname doc");

    Patient firstPatient = new Patient();
    firstPatient.setFirstName("patient 1");
    firstPatient.setLastName("patient lname1");

    firstDoctor.getPatients().add(firstPatient);
    firstPatient.getDoctorList().add(firstDoctor);

    rDoctor.save(firstDoctor);
}
```

Im using the standart CRUD repositories and the result of this is that I have a records in both Patient and Doctor tables, but the table doctor_patient is empty and never gets inserted with the correct data. 
How to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `@Transactional` it is rolling back that transaction..use below you should be good.

```
@Test
public void testSaveDoctor(){

    Doctor firstDoctor = new Doctor();
    firstDoctor.setFirstName("test doc");
    firstDoctor.setLastName("lname doc");

    Patient firstPatient = new Patient();
    firstPatient.setFirstName("patient 1");
    firstPatient.setLastName("patient lname1");

    firstDoctor.getPatients().add(firstPatient);
    firstPatient.getDoctorList().add(firstDoctor);

    rDoctor.save(firstDoctor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that I've added a @Transactional in the test description Hibernate was rolling back the result.Now after I remove it it works like a charm.

Comment: yeah..posted answer but you got it great